# Liferay JSON Web Services available at /api/jsonws is open access for any user

Tags: java, liferay-6, java-ee-6

On Liferay 6.2, the JSON Web Services are open access via `http://example.com/api/jsonws`. I know that I can restrict access to it to some special IPs via `portal-ext.properties`. But I want to grant this permission just to `Administrators` to see this page.  A [Liferay document](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/6-2/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/service-security-layers) says

> Liferay’s user permission layer is the last Liferay security layer triggered when services are invoked remotely.

But I couldn't find anything nor in `portal.properties` neither in `Control Panel/Roles` to set such permission for `Administrators` to prevent others from seeing `http://example.com/api/jsonws`.

Comment: solved: https://liferay.dev/forums/-/message_boards/message/118691482 - please link your crossposts in all directions in order to not generate duplicate work

Comment: Sorry for any inconvenience. Thanks for mentioning that. I repeated your comment and the digest of [the post in Liferay forum](https://liferay.dev/forums/-/message_boards/message/118704258) in an answer for more visibility and preventing duplicate work.

Answer (score 0):

As @Olaf Kock commented under my question, after not getting answered here, I repeated my question in [Liferay forum](https://liferay.dev/forums/-/message_boards/message/118704258). I repeat the digest of that thread here:

In Liferay 6.2, that page cannot be restricted using Permissions unless I write a hook. For Liferay 7.0+, this [post](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/securing-the-api-jsonws-ui) is helpful. Eventually, I used `jsonws.servlet.hosts.allowed` in *portal-ext.properties* and restricted the access to that page to some safe IPs.